# Convert mm/dd/yyyy format to date in R

Tags: r

I have this dataset in an access database:

```
Sample <- structure(list(SampleRowID = 164:173, StationCode = c("Gate 1", 
"Gate 1", "Gate 1", "Gate 1", "Gate 1", "Gate 1", "Gate 1", "Gate 1", 
"Gate 1", "Gate 1"), SampleDate = c(777427200, 777427200, 777513600, 
 777513600, 777600000, 777772800, 777859200, 777859200, 777859200, 
 777945600), SampleTime = c(-2209132440, -2209108440, -2209131900, 
-2209106280, -2209131420, -2209107120, -2209132140, -2209123680, 
-2209105800, -2209130640), MethodCode = c("RSTR", "RSTR", "RSTR", 
"RSTR", "RSTR", "RSTR", "RSTR", "RSTR", "RSTR", "RSTR"), SampleID = 
c("233_94", 
"234_94", "234_94", "235_94", "235_94", "238_94", "238_94", "239_94", 
"239_94", "239_94")), .Names = c("SampleRowID", "StationCode", 
"SampleDate", "SampleTime", "MethodCode", "SampleID"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-10L)) 

SampleRowID StationCode SampleDate  SampleTime MethodCode SampleID
      164      Gate 1  777427200 -2209132440       RSTR   233_94
      165      Gate 1  777427200 -2209108440       RSTR   234_94
      166      Gate 1  777513600 -2209131900       RSTR   234_94
      167      Gate 1  777513600 -2209106280       RSTR   235_94
      168      Gate 1  777600000 -2209131420       RSTR   235_94
      169      Gate 1  777772800 -2209107120       RSTR   238_94
      170      Gate 1  777859200 -2209132140       RSTR   238_94
      171      Gate 1  777859200 -2209123680       RSTR   239_94
      172      Gate 1  777859200 -2209105800       RSTR   239_94
      173      Gate 1  777945600 -2209130640       RSTR   239_94
```

The SampleDate is in format 01/04/2014, however, when I import to R my SampleDate columns get converted to numeric values. I used:

```
      Sample$SampleDate <- as.Date(Sample$SampleDate, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

but it doesn't work, I get the error:

```
      Error in as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(Sample$SampleDate, "%m/%d/%Y",  
      'origin' must be supplied
```

Then I supplied the origin like this:

```
       Sample$SampleDate <- as.Date(as.numeric(Sample$SampleDate, 
       "%m/%d/%Y",origin="01-01-1970"))
```

and get this error:

```
          Error in as.Date.numeric(as.numeric(Sample$SampleDate, "%m/%d/%Y", 
          origin = "1870-01-01")) : 
          'origin' must be supplied
```

The origin gets ignored. When I import my dataset from Access the date format changes to 'double' format. How can I convert back to my original date format? Any help is appreciated.

```
     UPDATE:
```

My table is being imported into R via MS Access -> then saved into a sqlite database. Then from R I make a connection to the sqlite database and import the 'Sample' table into the R workspace. I think sqlite is destroying my SampleDate format. If I save my 'Sample' table as csv format and import it into R then as.Date works well. I could provide the database with all of the R code I used if someone is interested in recreating my problem. I just can't reproduce the above here because I don't know how to post the access database.

Comment: how are you importing into `r`?

Comment: Salvador, I suggest you include (as @Nate suggested) the code you are using to import the data. I've never had a problem importing data when the date is in the clear format of `"%m/%d/%Y"`, so perhaps something else you're doing first is clobbering the import. If we can fix that, then most of the rest of this problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Sample$SampleDate <- as.Date(as.numeric(Sample$SampleDate, 
   "%m/%d/%Y",origin="01-01-1970"))
```

Here you called the `origin` argument in `as.numeric` instead of `as.Date`. But it doesn't really matter as the output isn't accurate.

```
> as.Date(as.numeric(Sample$SampleDate, "%m/%d/%Y"), origin="01-01-1970")
 [1] "2128524-06-06" "2128524-06-06" "2128760-12-26" "2128760-12-26" "2128997-07-16" "2129470-08-26"
 [7] "2129707-03-17" "2129707-03-17" "2129707-03-17" "2129943-10-06"
```

Your `SampleDate` date-time format looks like UNIX epoch, so `as.POSIXct` would be more appropriate.

```
> as.Date(as.POSIXct(Sample$SampleDate, origin="1970-01-01"))
 [1] "1994-08-21" "1994-08-21" "1994-08-22" "1994-08-22" "1994-08-23" "1994-08-25" "1994-08-26"
 [8] "1994-08-26" "1994-08-26" "1994-08-27"
```

Which looks more appropriate.

Comment: Why are you adding `"%m/%d/%H"` to your call to `as.numeric`? It's doing nothing. In fact, since the data in the OP is already numeric there, even `as.numeric` seems extraneous.

Comment: Where did I add `"%m/%d/%H"`? I didn't add anything, I just moved OP's `origin` call within `as.numeric` to `as.Date` as I didn't want to modify any other part of their code, but you're right it is extraneous.

Comment: I see, it's in the OP ... it's still unnecessary, but I guess that's why it's a question ...

Comment: This should work on a file imported directly from a csv or text file : as.Date(as.POSIXct(Sample$SampleDate, origin="1970-01-01")) but because my data is coming from an sqlite database, the SampleDate field format gets somehow destroyed.